# Swift: Print statement results in date that is different compared to the initial one

Tags: swift, date

I ran into a very weird behaviour of my app.

Broken down a date is being changed when using it further down in the app. Please see below for an easy example from a Playground.

Do you have an idea what's behind that behaviour?

Many thanks in advance!

```
import SwiftUI

var dateComponent = DateComponents()
dateComponent.day = 17
dateComponent.month = 5
dateComponent.year = 1989
dateComponent.calendar = Calendar.current
let date = Calendar.current.date(from: dateComponent) ?? Date()
```

[image: date data in playground]

```
print(date)
```

**Output:**

[image: Print date output]

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature. `print` shows dates always in UTC. Your timezone is clearly UTC +0200 so `1989-05-16 22:00:00 +0000` and `1989-05-17 00:00:00 +0200` is exactly the same point in time.

Comment: Thank you all! Understood what's caused the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One is your local time, the other is the GMT time.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing timezone like this

```
dateComponent.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "JST")
```

Comment: Thank you. This indeed works but is not what I wanted (as not correct for users depending on their timezones). In my code above I understand that I set the timezone to "current" which unfortunately is producing different results.